# Ao clicar no checkbox desabilitar o botão

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código que traz automaticamente o valor do frete:

```
foreach($dados->cServico as $linhas) {

    if($linhas->Codigo == '04014'){
        $servico = "SEDEX";
    }
    if($linhas->Codigo == '04510'){
        $servico = "PAC";
    }
    echo "<input type='radio' name='Servico[]' value='".$linhas->Valor."' id='servicos' onclick='desabilitar()'> <strong>".$servico."</strong><br>";

}
```

Com esse código, tenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enquanto o usuário não selecionar qual modalidade vai querer, o botão fica desabilitado. Para isso estou usando o seguinte código:

```
    function desabilitar(){
        if(document.getElementById('servicos').checked == true){
             document.getElementById('botao').disabled = "";
        }
        if(document.getElementById('servicos').checked == false){
             document.getElementById('botao').disabled = "disabled";
        }
    }
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px" id="botao" disabled><h4>Finalizar <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4></button>
```

O problema é quando seleciono o Sedex, o botão funciona perfeitamente, mas quando clico no PAC, o botão volta a desabilitar. Como faço para que ao clicar no Sedex ou PAC o botão fique habilitado, caso contrário, o botão fica desabilitado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não podes ter IDs duplicados, a sintaxe de HTML só permite 1 ID unico por página.

Muda `id='servicos'` para classes `class='servicos'` ou passa o `this` no HTML assim: `onclick='desabilitar(this)'>` e depois:

```js
function desabilitar(el) {
  document.getElementById('botao').disabled = !el.checked;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio. Funcionou.

Comment: Sérgio. Me desculpe, implementei seu código, mas como eu faria para pegar o valor do input, pois eu precisava pegar o valor do frete. No caso do ID eu pegava dessa forma: **valorFrete = document.getElementById("servicos").innerHTML;**

Comment: @Fox.11 dentro da função ou fora? Onde chamas o código que procura esse valor? Assim sem testar creio que podes usar `document.querySelector("[name='Servico[]']:checked");`

Comment: Olá Sergio. Seria dentro da função.

Comment: @Fox.11 nesse caso `el.value`dá o valor do input cujo `this` passaste em `onclick='desabilitar(this)'>`

Comment: Perfeito Sergio. Obrigado mais uma vez.